# Drawing a perpendicular line with the package tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

How to draw a perpendicular line from "P" to segment "AB"?

[image: Picture]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,xcolor,graphicx}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
\coordinate(A)at(0,0);
\coordinate(B)at(5,0);
\coordinate(P)at(3.7896542,3);

\draw[thick](A)--(B);

\tkzDrawPoint[color=red](A)
 \tkzLabelPoint[below=2pt](A){$A$}
\tkzDrawPoint[color=red](B)
 \tkzLabelPoint[below=2pt](B){$B$}


\tkzDrawPoint[fill=yellow](P)
 \tkzLabelPoint[above=2pt](P){$P$}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(P)` and get `p` from there.

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,xcolor,graphicx}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 5/0/B, 3.7896542/3/P}

\draw[thick](A)--(B);

\tkzDrawPoints[color=red](A,B)
\tkzLabelPoint[below=2pt](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below=2pt](B){$B$}

\tkzDrawPoint[fill=yellow](P)
\tkzLabelPoint[above=2pt](P){$P$}

\tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(P) \tkzGetPoint{p}
\tkzDrawSegment(P,p)

\tkzLabelPoint[below=2pt](p){$p$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have another question. How to draw a circle which has got the same radius as the length of segment P,p? The middle of the circle is the point P.

Comment: @ostal123 I think that deserves to be a whole new question.

Answer (score 2):

TikZ provides a special syntax for projections.  So you could add

```
\draw (P) -- ($(A)!(P)!(B)$);
```

before you label the points.  But `tkz-euclide` also provides

```
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through P](B,A)
\tkzGetPoint{p}
\draw (P)--(p);
```

although in this latter case, point `(p)` does **not** lie on the line AB.

Comment: And how to make the point (p) to lie on the segment AB?