# Orthogonal line in tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am trying to find the intersection of (A,B) with the orthogonal line through P. The following code results in "No shape named C is known":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(11,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(10,10){P}
  \tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through P](B,A) \tkzGetPoint{X_1}
  \tkzInterLL(P,X_1)(A,B) \tkzGetPoint(C)
  \tkzLabelPoints(C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and I don't understand why that intersection point should not exist.

Comment: Wrong braces. Use \tkzGetPoint{C} instead of \tkzGetPoint(C).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282879/drawing-a-perpendicular-line-with-the-package-tkz-euclide on the right in the Related-list.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Would you put your comment as an answer, which can be accepted so this question can then disappear from the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to use `\tkzGetPoint{C}` instead of `\tkzGetPoint(C)`. Syntax change.

I also added (drawing) the points and lines with `\tkzDrawPoints(C,X_1)` and `\tkzDrawLine(A,B)` to visualize the solution. `\tkzLabelPoints(A,B)` plots the label.

***Define a orthogonal line to a other line (A,B) going through a Ponit P:***
Therefore you can use `\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through P](B,A)`, the second point of the line you can get with `\tkzGetPoint{X_1}`(first point is P) defined as X_1.

***Compute the intersection of two line:***
`\tkzInterLL(P,X_1)(A,B)`: computes the intersection of the two lines (P,X_1) and (A,B). With `\tkzGetPoint{C}` you get the intersection point, saved as C.

**Solution:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(11,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(10,10){P}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,P)\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,P)
  %
  \tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through P](B,A)     
  \tkzGetPoint{X_1}
  %  
  \tkzInterLL(P,X_1)(A,B)
  \tkzGetPoint{C}
  \tkzDrawPoints(C,X_1)\tkzLabelPoints(C,X_1)
  %
   \tkzDrawLine(A,B)
   \tkzDrawLine(P,X_1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```